# Silverlight Usercontrol Onload Event when generated in another Usercontrol, to apply farseer physics

Tags: silverlight, farseer

Didn't know how to phrase the question better but basically I have a usercontrol that I dynamically add into another usercontrol. The child usercontrol has a set of images and basically I need to know if they have fully loaded inside the parent usercontrol since I need their dimentions for a method (not just height and width).

Is there a type of event that can trigger when all the images in the child usercontrol have loaded in the parent?

To further explain my scenario, I need this since I am using farseer physics engine for silverlight and it aquires the shape of the image to use for collision detection, and since when I try to turn the images into a physics object it would not find the shape since the image is still being generated on screen and therefore throws an exception.

Update: This is what I have came up with so far

```
void currImg_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var ImagesLoaded = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < ImageLoaded.Count-1; i++)
    {
        if (!ImageLoaded[i])
        {
            ImagesLoaded = false;
            ImageLoaded[i] = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (ImagesLoaded)
    {
        addPuppetPhysics(pg.currPuppet);
    }

}
```

Where `ImageLoaded` is a list of booleans, the method `addPuppetPhysics` applies the farseer physics to the usercontrol `pg.currPuppet` . Thing is the physics engine finds the first half of the images then doesn't find anymore (crashes on the same Image). If I merely load the usercontrol, then apply the physics with a button click, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you detect when the images are finished loading in the child control?  If so you may be able to create you own event -- ex: `ImagesLoaded` -- and handle that in the parent.

Comment: Well I am using silverlight 3 beta and there is ImageOpened event but seems to trigger before the usercontrol is fully loaded